# How to set a JavaFX Stage/Frame to Maximized

Tags: frame, stage, javafx-2, maximize-window

I'm using JavaFX 2. I want my frame to open maximized but I'm not seeing a way. I searched a bit on the internet without success. For the stage I see `setFullScreen()` and `setIconified()` but I don't see anything like `setMaximized()`.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

When evaluating the sourcecode of the Ensemble.jar provided with the samples of JavaFX 2.0 SDK, the currently valid way to achieve window maximizing is

```
Screen screen = Screen.getPrimary();
Rectangle2D bounds = screen.getVisualBounds();

primaryStage.setX(bounds.getMinX());
primaryStage.setY(bounds.getMinY());
primaryStage.setWidth(bounds.getWidth());
primaryStage.setHeight(bounds.getHeight());
```

(you find similar code in WindowButtons.java)

The 'maximize' button is still enabled and when clicking it, the windows will grow a bit more (Windows OS). After this the 'maximize 'button is disabled. In the provided example the standard buttons are replaced. Maybe this is still an issue.

Comment: I agree. This looks like an issue. But Thanks. this will work for now.

Comment: There is a feature request for that http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-10376 -- you may want to vote for it to get it done sooner rather then later.

Comment: While this seems the best we can do right now, there are many issues with this approach. For example it lacks the ability to reliably tell if a window is maximizes (so it can be saved/restored in session management) and it also doesn't work easily with multiple screens. You would have to iterate through `Screen.getScreens()` and find the one the window is on. JavaFX feels like Swing all over again in so many ways :-)

Comment: PS: it's also not easy to undo the maximize given that it seems hard to track when it is happening (the only thing I can think of is to listen to both width and height changes and check if it seems to be the full size -- plus minus the bits that Windows likes to add. Buyer beware.

Comment: This isn't technically maximized mode, either. It's just an unmaximized window that is the size of the screen.

Comment: Hi, This method was working earlier but it just stopped working.  I haven't changed in Maximize Button code. But somehow it just stopped working.

Answer (score 156):

The Java 8 implementation of the Stage class provides a maximized property, which can be set as follows:

```
primaryStage.setMaximized(true);
```

Comment: A small addition for the cases if the code above still doesn't work - call setMaximized() after calling show().

Comment: @AramParonikyan I had a problem with the code above.  But calling show() alone, like you mentioned, doesn't solved the issue. I tried first to hide the stage with `stage.hide();` and then `stage.setMaximized(true);` and after that I called `stage.show();` and that solved it. But anyways thanks for the hint! :)

Comment: @Kami :) Very odd practices, Kami, maybe the issue is in the OS environment? Mine was Ubuntu with the latest Oracle Java8

Comment: @AramParonikyan I'm using also Ubuntu and the Problem only occurs on ubuntu. JavaFX works on Windows without problems. Maybe the next update from Oracle could solve this. :)

Comment: Hey, this is not an answer since this will not work if the stage's style is set to other values than DECORATED and UTIL

Comment: Best solution for java 8

Comment: Works perfectly fine for me on Linux Mint XFCE (Java 17), even with an undecorated stage...

Answer (score 8):

try this simpler code 
`primaryStage.setMaximized(true);`
and it fills up the whole screen
. note that if you remove maximize/minise buttons the application will fill the whole screen as well as remove the taskbar so mnd your `initStyles` if you have any

Comment: Combine this with the **Multi-Screen compatible maximize logic** to address the _full screen_ issue. First `setMaximized`, then use `getVisualBounds` to set the X, Y, width and height of the stage.

Answer (score 7):

Better use **Multi-Screen compatible** maximize logic:

```
// Get current screen of the stage      
ObservableList<Screen> screens = Screen.getScreensForRectangle(new Rectangle2D(stage.getX(), stage.getY(), stage.getWidth(), stage.getHeight()));

// Change stage properties
Rectangle2D bounds = screens.get(0).getVisualBounds();
stage.setX(bounds.getMinX());
stage.setY(bounds.getMinY());
stage.setWidth(bounds.getWidth());
stage.setHeight(bounds.getHeight());
```

Comment: As with another answer, this isn't maximized; it's just the same size as the screen.

Answer (score -7):

Use this to remove the Minimise, Maximise Buttons :

```
primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);
```

Where primaryStage is your Stage object.